How to plot ℝ²→ℝ² functions in MATLAB?
I was wondering if it possible to plot (the image of) ℝ²→ℝ² functions in MATLAB so that the generated figure consists of the transformed grid e.g.

It would be of further help if the figure could identify each point of the transformed grid with its preimage; such a thing may be done by labelling a few points or by coloring the grid differently depending on the x and y coordinates of the preimage.

Aren't these just line plots of multiples of unit vectors?

Yes, indeed it is possible
1.
The 'mapping' you ask for is called Conformal Mapping.
A concise article explaining Conformal Mapping in MATLAB with code examples  available here :
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/exploring-a-conformal-mapping.html
If one looks for just 'mapping' or '2D mapping' then most of the obtained links refer to terrain mapping only.
2. One particular type of conformal mapping are the bilinear transform.
The Wikipedia article titled Bilinear Transform gives this name to H(s) doing s=1j*w where s Complex, perhaps the best known bilinear transform
but
another popular bilinear transform is the Smith Chart that maps infine R+1j*X passive impedances into a circle.
As explained in the following link
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1002/0471723770.app1?download=true
The general form of any bilinear transformation is
Z=(a+b*z)/(c+d*z)
where in general a, b, c, and d are Complex
Please let us know whether the above Mathworks article is enough to get you started.

While I appreciate the answer, conformal mappings are a very small subset of all ℝ²→ℝ² maps. I want a general method for visualizing all ℝ²→ℝ² maps.

1.- In MATLAB ℝ²→ℝ²  mapping is done processing the input points as an image.
However, considering the image included in this question showing such specific grid-like output sought:
You are not just asking how to do any  ℝ²→ℝ²functions in MATLAB but how to generate grid-like outputs similar to the one shown in the image attached to your question.
In this answer I map points with certain step, but additional points along each input grid line are calculated to avoid having to interpolate between adjacent grid points.
8 example functions are used, all results consistent with Wolfram examples on conformal mapping.
Wolfram also has a widget available here to calculate ℝ²→ℝ² of custom functions.
clear all;close all;clc

dx1=1;
x1=[-10:dx1:10];                              % grid limits
y1=x1;
nx=numel(x1);ny=numel(y1);

ms=2;                                              % marker size
a0=15;
a1=1;

k0=1;

dx2=dx1/10;                                     % shorter step for single line calculations
dy2=dx2;

Zin=zeros(ny,nx,2);                           % input points
Zout=Zin;
Zin(:,:,1)=repmat(x1,ny,1);
Zin(:,:,2)=repmat(y1',1,nx);

% functions list
f1_cell={'@(a0,a1,z) a0*a1./z;','@(a0,a1,z) a0*a1*z.^2;','@(a0,a1,z) a1./(a0*z.^2);',...
'@(a0,a1,z) a1*(a0*z).^.5;','@(a0,a1,z) a1*(a0./z).^.5;','@(a0,a1,z) a1*exp(1).^(a0*z);',...
'@(a0,a1,z) a0*sin(z/a1);','@(a0,a1,z) a0*cos(z/a1);' };

% coeffs for each function
a0a1=[15 1;
    .1 1;
    .01 3;
    1 3;
    2 7;
    .35 10;
    5 3;
    5 3];

Ax_lim=[-8.5 8.5 -8.5 8.5;    % zoom in/out for each function
-15 15 -15 15;  
-19 15 -13 14;  
-12 12 -12 12
-10 15 -10 10; 
-3 3 -3 3;  
-10 10 -10 6;  
-10 10 -10 6]; 

for k0=1:1:8
 
    figure(k0)
    ax=gca;
    axis(ax,'equal');
    grid(ax,'off');
    hold(ax,'all');
    
    f1_str= f1_cell{k0};    
                r2_to_r2(Zin,a0a1(k0,1),a0a1(k0,2),str2func(f1_str),ax,nx,ny,dx2,dy2,ms);
        
    title(ax,['Example ' num2str(k0) ' f(z) = ' f1_str([11:end])]);
    
    axis(ax,Ax_lim(k0,:));
    
    exportgraphics(ax,['upload_0' num2str(k0) '.jpg'],'Resolution',100)
    
end









2.- The support function doing all hard work is :
function r2_to_r2(Zin,a0,a1,f1,ax,nx,ny,dx2,dy2,ms)
% suport function for ex01_5.m

for k2=1:1:ny                                  % input grid
       plot(ax,[Zin(k2,1,1) Zin(k2,nx,1)],[Zin(k2,1,2) Zin(k2,1,2)],'Color',[.9 .9 .9]);  
end
for k1=1:1:nx
      plot(ax,[Zin(1,k1,1) Zin(1,k1,1)],[Zin(1,k1,2) Zin(ny,k1,2)],'Color',[.9 .9 .9]);  
end

for k2=1:1:ny                                  % output grid horizontal lines
       Lxin_horz=[Zin(k2,1,1):dx2:Zin(k2,nx,1)];
       Lyin_horz=[Zin(k2,1,2):dy2:Zin(k2,1,2)];
       Lin_horz=Lxin_horz+1j*Lyin_horz;
       Lout_horz=f1(a0,a1,Lin_horz);            % f(z)=a0*z^2
       Lxout_horz=real(Lout_horz);
       Lyout_horz=imag(Lout_horz);
       
       plot(ax,Lxout_horz,Lyout_horz,'Color','b');  
end

for k1=1:1:nx                                   % output grid vertical lines
       Lxin_vert=[Zin(1,k1,1):dy2:Zin(1,k1,1)];
       Lyin_vert=[Zin(1,k1,2):dy2:Zin(ny,k1,2)];
       Lin_vert=Lxin_vert+1j*Lyin_vert;
       Lout_vert= f1(a0,a1,Lin_vert);              % f(z)=a0*z^2
       Lxout_vert=real(Lout_vert);
       Lyout_vert=imag(Lout_vert);
      plot(ax,Lxout_vert,Lyout_vert,'Color','r');  
end

Zout=f1(a0,a1,Zin);

for k1=1:1:nx                                   % output grid points
    for k2=1:1:ny
        zout=f1(a0,a1,Zin(k1,k2,1)+1j*Zin(k1,k2,2));
        plot(ax,real(zout),imag(zout),'LineStyle','none','Marker','d','MarkerSize',ms,'MarkerFaceColor','c','MarkerEdgeColor','c');  
    end
end

end

3.- In early attempts before using vertical and horizontal 'comb' I did the following errors :
3.1.-

instead of

3.2.-

instead of

3.3.- boom

3.4.- bang

3.5.- wrong

